# Datatable Union using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

My data table dt has columns are as below

**Name, Value, key, IsMarkets, IsBudgets, IsPrograms**

I have 3 check boxes chkbxBudgetsSearch,chkbxMarketsSearch,chkbxProgramsSearch

I want dt  to be filtered on following condition

if chkbxMarketsSearch.IsChecked == true 
all rows with  IsMarkets=True should be displayed

if chkbxBudgetsSearch.IsChecked == true 
all rows with  IsBudgets=True should be displayed

similarly for programs

and if both  check boxes are clicked then
all rows with  IsMarkets=True and IsBudgets=False / IsMarkets=False and IsBudgets=True
/ IsMarkets=True and IsBudgets=True  should be displayed

Note : its need not be only IsMarkets=True and IsBudgets=True

Its close to union operation 
Can anyone wrire linq for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now that the question has changed:

```
var result = Enumerable.Empty<DataRow>();
var linqTable = table.AsEnumerable();
if (chkbxMarketsSearch.IsChecked)
{
    results = results.Union(linqTable.Where(row => row.Field<bool>("IsMarkets"));
}
if (chkbxBudgetsSearch.IsChecked)
{
    results = results.Union(linqTable.Where(row => row.Field<bool>("IsBudgets"));
}
if (chkbxProgramsSearch.IsChecked)
{
    results = results.Union(linqTable.Where(row => row.Field<bool>("IsPrograms"));
}
// Probably best to call `ToList()` here before doing much more work...
```

Note that if none of the checkboxes is ticked, you won't get any results.

Comment: no this will retrieve results if any one of the condition is true. thats not wat i want . fa eg if  IsMarkets is true and IsBudgets is false then only records with those IsMarkets is true should be retreived

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh: I don't understand. Are you saying you have query *inputs* called IsMarkets and IsBudgets as well as columns in your table? My answer is correct for the question you *asked*, but it sounds like you didn't ask for what you actually need. You should clarify your question. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Some sample data would help... as well as being *very* clear about what the inputs to the query are beyond the data table itself.